# .htaccess concatenating www + subdomain

Tags: .htaccess

I'm running a new Drupal 7 site on Ubuntu 14 (so no httpd.conf file), and am trying to make a simple htaccess rule to redirect from no subdomain to www. Basic stuff, the Internet told me what to do, and I used this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.[^.]+$
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Problem is that if I put in a subdomain - something.domain.com - it concatenates the URL to www.something.domain.com

How can I get around this? It's... quite annoying. Perhaps a module would be a better solution than an .htaccess update?

(Also Global Redirect Case Sensitive URL Checking isn't working, but that's another story...)

Thanks.

Comment: How many domain names are pointing to the Drupal site?
something.domain.com, www.something.domain.com, domain.com, & www.domain.com?

Comment: At the moment none; we have a wildcard in our DNS where any undefined subdomain will default to the content of WWW.

(Accidental enter press...)

We do have a couple of live subdomains that point to different servers, and those are defined in the DNS and not causing any issues.

Comment: The issue, as I realize I didn't elaborate on, is things like wwww.site.com will create www.wwww.site.com, and Google will spider the whole thing and ding us badly for duplicate content.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it os about Apache, not Drupal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to redirect everyone to the www version of the site.
How about this.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

It will redirect anything that isn't www.example.com to www.example.com and pass along the url.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/intro.html has more options you can use.